# How do GCLatencyMode and gcConcurrent interact in .Net 4.5.1 (using gcserver)

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, .net-4.5, low-latency

I can set the GCLatencyMode to `Batch`, `Interactive` or `SustainedLowLatency`. Does varying the value of the `<gcConcurrent>` element ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwwzef8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) give me any additional options on top of the latency mode? It's not immediately obvious how these things interact (other than `Batch` disables `concurrent`).

I'm using server GC.

Comment: Note: From experimentation, varying `gcConcurrent` doesn't appear to give me any new options over the `GCLatencyMode`, but it's hard to be certain.

Comment: http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/04/13/performance-analysis-comparing-interactive-and-low-latency-gc-strategies-in-net/

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd create an answer to this, now that we have some clarity from the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/latency). Have run some tests to confirm this behaviour.

Varying `gcConcurrent` will not give you additional options but will have an affect on which latency modes are available:

- If `gcConcurrent` is disabled, then it is not possible to set the
  latency mode to `SustainedLowLatency` - it will just default to
  `Batch` as if `GCSettings.LatencyMode` were not set. It is still possible to set it to `LowLatency`.
- If `gcConcurrent` is enabled, then you can set the latency mode to either `SustainedLowLatency` or `LowLatency`. Then if `GCSettings.LatencyMode` is not set, it will default to `Interactive`